# Automatically responding to "openssl req" prompts?

Tags: openssl

When you use `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key my.key -days 366 -out my.pem` to generate a self-signed certificate, it prompts you for a bunch of information, such as "Country Name (2 letter code)", etc.

Is there any way to automate the responses to these prompts, making the process non-interactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
SUBJ="/C=DK/ST=Jylland/O=Company Name"
openssl req -new -key ca.key -x509 -days 3653 -out ca.crt -subj "$SUBJ"
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm trying to generate a one-off CA / server certificate chain for unit testing, and it needed to be scripted.